# How to fit a weighted mixed effects model?

Tags: r, mixed-model, weighted-regression

I am looking to get help into specifying the structure of the variance matrix within the `gls()` function in R's nlme package (or recommendations of other packages that can achieve the same thing).

### Terminology

Let:

- $Y_{ij}$ be an observed value for subject $i$ who is in group $j$
- $X_i$ be the subjects matrix of covariates
- $i = 1,\dots,n$
- $j = 1,2$
- $\mu_i = f(X_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \dots$ (a linear model)
- $\sigma_j^2$ be the unexplained variance (1 per each group)
- $w_i$ be the per subject weighting

### My question

Using R's `nlme::gls()` (or any equivalent package) how do I fit the model:

$$
Y_{ij} \sim N(\mu_i, w_i \sigma^2_j)
$$

### What I've tried so far

I believe `gls( data = dat , OBS ~ VAR1 + VAR2, weights = NULL)`  fits

$$
Y_{ij} \sim N(\mu_i , \sigma^2)
$$

I believe `gls( data = dat_w , OBS ~ VAR1 + VAR2, weights = varFixed(~WEIGHT))` fits

$$
Y_{ij} \sim N(\mu_i , w_i\sigma^2)
$$

I believe `gls( data = dat_g , OBS ~ VAR1 + VAR2, weights = varIdent(form = ~1 | GROUP))` fits:

$$
Y_{ij} \sim N(\mu_i , \sigma^2_j)
$$

But I still can't for the life of me figure out how to fit:

$$
Y_{ij} \sim N(\mu_i , w_i\sigma^2_j)
$$

:(

(Happy to share the code that generates the simulated datasets upon request)

### Disclaimer

I am aware this question is more programming focused and may be better positioned on stack exchange however in my experience questions relating to statistical implementation don't get good response rates over there so please forgive me for posting this here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `varComb` as in this example

```r
# simulate
set.seed(49743640)
n <- 50L                                   # number of subjects
X <- matrix(rnorm(n * 2L), ncol = 2L)      # covariates
w_i <- sample(1/(1:10), n, replace = TRUE) # weights
grp <- gl(n = 2L, n, labels = c("a", "b")) # group variable
id <- rep(1:n, 2L)                         # id
sig <- c(3, 3 * 2)                         # sigma

eta <- 1.5 + X %*% c(-2, 3)
y1 <- rnorm(n, eta, sd = sig[1] * sqrt(w_i))
y2 <- rnorm(n, eta, sd = sig[2] * sqrt(w_i))

dt <- data.frame(y = c(y1, y2), X, grp = grp, w = w_i)

# fit model
library(nlme)
fit <- gls(data = dt, y ~ X1 + X2, weights = varComb(
  varIdent(form = ~ 1 | grp), varFixed(~ w)))
summary(fit)
#R Generalized least squares fit by REML
#R   Model: y ~ X1 + X2 
#R   Data: dt 
#R   AIC BIC logLik
#R   436 449   -213
#R 
#R Combination of variance functions: 
#R  Structure: Different standard deviations per stratum
#R  Formula: ~1 | grp 
#R  Parameter estimates:
#R    a    b 
#R 1.00 1.93 
#R Variance function:
#R  Structure: fixed weights
#R  Formula: ~w 
#R 
#R Coefficients:
#R             Value Std.Error t-value p-value
#R (Intercept)  1.43     0.168    8.56       0
#R X1          -1.88     0.170  -11.05       0
#R X2           3.26     0.171   19.11       0
#R 
#R  Correlation: 
#R    (Intr) X1   
#R X1 0.015       
#R X2 0.022  0.146
#R 
#R Standardized residuals:
#R     Min      Q1     Med      Q3     Max 
#R -2.5799 -0.5589  0.0327  0.6712  2.8004 
#R 
#R Residual standard error: 3.11 
#R Degrees of freedom: 100 total; 97 residual

# confirm weights
v_obj <- varComb(varIdent(c("b" = 2), form = ~ 1 | grp), varFixed(~ w))
v_obj <- Initialize(v_obj, dt)
head((1/varWeights(v_obj))^2) # varWeights yields inverse standard deviations
#R [1] 0.125 0.200 0.100 0.143 0.167 1.000
head(w_i) * 1L
#R [1] 0.125 0.200 0.100 0.143 0.167 1.000

tail(varWeights(v_obj)^(-2))
#R [1] 0.400 1.333 1.000 0.444 2.000 0.400
tail(w_i) * 2^2
#R [1] 0.400 1.333 1.000 0.444 2.000 0.400
```

### Why does this work

From `help("varComb")`

> The corresponding variance function is equal to the product of the variance functions of the `varFunc` objects listed in `...`.

So

```
varComb(varIdent(form = ~ 1 | grp), varFixed(~ w))
```

implies that the variance is

$$
\sigma_{ij}^2 = \sigma^2 w_i \delta_j^2 
   = w_i\sigma_j^2, \qquad \sigma_j = \sigma\delta_j$$

where $\sigma = 3$ is unknown, $\delta_1 = 1$, $\delta_2 = 2$ is unknown, and $w_i$ are fixed weights.

Comment: Please can you explain why this answer is solution to the problem im the OP

Comment: Does the updated answer make it clear?